# GORM model with custom datatype

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to initialize my database and create the tables for the models I declared. I have a model called Analytics with has a set of properties with a custom data type (structs I created). When I try to run the app, it gives me an error

> invalid field found for struct github.com/csidi90/cryptodashboard-go/models.Analytics's field RSI, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

I have other models that had relations to custom data types which worked fine. In this case, there is no relation between tables I just want to store the custom structs inside that model. Is that not possible easily?

I have the app connected to a MySQL Database.

```
type Analytics struct {
ID        uint64        `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
RSI       analytics.RSI `json:"rsi"`
SMA50     analytics.SMA `json:"sma50"`
SMA100    analytics.SMA `json:"sma100"`
SMA200    analytics.SMA `json:"sma200"`
Timeframe string        `json:"timeframe" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_analytics;size:5"`
TickerID  uint64        `json:"ticker_id"`
}
```